# swift function not returning string?

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a function to return a username with a Firebase query on the userID parameter. I want to use this username to populate the text labels in a tableView. Although the query within the function returns the correct value, the value does not seem to be returned:

```
func getUser(userID: String) -> String {

        var full_name: String = ""
        rootRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let first_name = snapshot.value!["first_name"] as! String
            let last_name = snapshot.value!["last_name"] as! String
            full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
            print(full_name) // returns correct value
        })
        return full_name //printing outside here just prints a blank space in console
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let inviteDict = invites[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]
        if let userID = inviteDict["invitedBy"] as? String {

            let name = getUser(userID)

            cell.textLabel!.text = name
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

The cells don't have text. Printing the function return to console just prints blank space. Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `getUser` function executes an block to get the `full_name` value, but you are returning on another thread, so when this line  `return full_name` executes, is almost impossible that your block has ended so your function returns `""` instead of your desired value

try this instead

```
func getUser(userID: String,closure:((String) -> Void)?) -> Void {

        var full_name: String = ""
        rootRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let first_name = snapshot.value!["first_name"] as! String
            let last_name = snapshot.value!["last_name"] as! String
            full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
            print(full_name) // returns correct value
            closure(full_name)
        })
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let inviteDict = invites[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]
        if let userID = inviteDict["invitedBy"] as? String {

            let name = getUser(userID, closure: { (name) in
                cell.textLabel!.text = name
            })
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I hope this helps you, PS I am not sure if this works because i don't have this library

Comment: That worked! So...why did your solution work? What is a "closure"? Thank you so much!!